# How to exclude a component from build process depending on env. variable?'

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to exclude a component from build process. But this should happen based on environment variable saved in `environment.prod.ts`.

I have been searching but didn't find a working solution, and the most hints are talking about something like adding `exclude` property in `tsconfig.app.json`. But even if this suggestion would work, it can't be conditional based on an environment variable, cause this is not possible in this scenario (`tsconfig.app.json`).

Example of how the entry in environment could be used:

`export const environment = {
  production: true,
  buildComponentX: false/true
};`

Any Hint or idea how such process could be implemented?

Comment: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-tips-dynamic-module-imports-with-the-angular-cli. If you are using this, and your compilation is runtime, then you should be able to use a switch like you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

**I didn't test this, this is just a lead.**

Since your components are bundled at compilation time, why not create an array that contains your components based on a query ?

```
const components = [AppComponent, PublicComponent, RestrictedComponent, ProdComponent];
const componentsToExport = components.filter(component => component !== ProdComponent);
export componentsToExport;
```

Now in your modules, you can import this array and spread it :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...componentsToExport]
  // And the rest
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: The idea looks good. But to be honest I'am not sure where the components array should be saved. Should be in `app.components`, right? And how would I implement also an env. var. based on your example? I need the env .var. to be flexible and exclude it from build when needed.

Comment: read https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be for using environment variable, then try the above approach. The problem that I have is that `filter`, will this code run before compilation?

Comment: If I were you, I would make it in another file, say `conditional-imports.ts`. Then, you would just need to import `env` into your file, and the variable would contain either the list of arrays, or you could change your condition to `component !== ProdComponent && env.production`. At this point, that's just up to you, I can't decide for you, there are several solutions !

Comment: @trichetriche: Sry, now I'am a kind of confused ;-( this means a variable would be in env. something like: `export const environment = {...., ....., components: [AppComponent, PublicComponent, RestrictedComponent, ProdComponent, ....];}` this won't work. and why should I use this in other case `&& env.production`. My target is to keep it simple and check if `ComponentX: true`, then `ComponentX` will be included in build, if `ComponentX: false`, then `ComponentX` will be excluded.

Comment: For the first solution, why this would not work ? And for the second solution, if you want to put a condition on 3 components, You will have to write `componentX: true, componentY: true, componentZ: true` and so on. Imagine you have 40 ... With `production: true`, you can use a single boolean for all components at once.

Comment: For the first option, the array entries should be then strings e.g. `components: ['AppComponent', 'PublicComponent', 'RestrictedComponent', 'ProdComponent']`, otherwise error for each array-entry e.g. `[ts] Cannot find name 'AppComponent'.`

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be a string. But you might be right about it not working, but because of circular dependencies (and this issue is up to you and your imports). And this error pops because you didn't import the file, not because it isn't possible.

Comment: Yes, true, I don't want to import the files/components in `environment.ts` and that's why the error. Makes sense of course

Comment: Makes sense to you ... Not to me :) So, bottom line, try the next solution ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172427/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-trichetriche).

Comment: I would argue that this is going to work at all as this is runtime code, so everything will be compiled and bundled first.